# Xcode adding constraints so an ImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I'm making an app in Xcode where there is a trunk in the middle of the screen and a branch on the right as you can see in the image (I've put two buttons which represent the trunk and the branch. The blue button is the trunk while the red one is the branch).

Using the constraints I managed to resize the trunk properly in every iPhone device, but I am not able to do the same with the branch.

Can you tell me how to keep this configuration of the trunk and the branch using constraints?

I've tried adding:
-Align horizontally in container, using the "Current canvas value"
-Aspect ratio
-Aspect ratio in proportion with the Trunk
but it doesn't work

Here is the image of the buttons which represents the trunk and the branch:

[image: Tree and branch in emulator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with 8 constraints:

1. BlueButton.Top = Superview.Top.Margin
2. BlueButton.Bottom = BottomLayoutGuide.Top
3. BlueButton.Width = Superview.Width with multiplier `3:10`
4. BlueButton.CenterX = Superview.CenterX
5. RedButton.Leading = BlueButton.Trailing
6. RedButton.Trailing = Superview.Trailing.Margin
7. RedButton.Width = RedButton.Height with multiplier `10:3`
8. RedButton.Bottom = Superview.Bottom with multiplier `0.4` (to make branch 60% of way up the tree)

---

**To create constraints 1 and 2:**

Click on the blue button to select it.  Click on the *Pin* <kbd>[-[]-]</kbd> icon.  Turn on the top and bottom orange I-beams and click <kbd>[Add 2 Constraints]</kbd>.

**To create constraint 3:**

<kbd>control</kbd>-drag from blue button to white background.  Choose *Equal Widths* from the pop-up.  To set the multiplier, click again on the blue button and find the *Equal width to superview* constraint in the *Size Inspector* on the right.  Click on *Edit* and set the multiplier to `3:10`.

**To create constraint 4:**

<kbd>control</kbd>-drag from blue button to white background.  Choose *Center Horizontally in Container* from the pop-up.

**To create constraint 5:**

<kbd>control</kbd>-drag from blue button to red button.  Choose *Horizontal Spacing* from the pop-up.

**To create constraint 6:**

<kbd>control</kbd>-drag upwards at a 45 degree angle from center of the red button to the right edge of the background.  Choose *Trailing Space to Container Margin* from the pop-up.

**To create constraint 7:**

Completely inside the red button, <kbd>control</kbd>-drag up and to the right.  Choose *Aspect Ratio* from the pop-up.  Find the *Ratio* constraint in the *Size Inspector*, click on *Edit* and set the *multiplier* to `10:3`.

**To create constraint 8:**

This last one is the hardest, but you can do it!  Click on the red button.  Now, in the *Document Outline* to the left of the Storyboard you'll see that the button is highlighted in gray.  Hold down the <kbd>command</kbd> key and click on the `View` that contains the button.  It should look like this when both the view and the button are highlighted:

[image]

Now, click on the *Align Icon* (to the left of *Pin* <kbd>[-[]-]</kbd>), click the checkbox for *Bottom Edges*, and click <kbd>[Add 1 Constraint]</kbd>.

Now, click on your red button again, and find the *Bottom Space to: Superview* constraint in the *Size Inspector*.  Double click on it to open it up:

[image: Bottom Space to: Superview constraint]

This is what we want it to look like.  You'll probably have to change 2 things.  If your *first item* is *Superview.Bottom* then you'll need to swap the first and second items.  To do that, click on *Superview.Bottom* and choose *Reverse first and second items*.

Next, change the multiplier to `0.4`  This means that the red button's bottom is 40% of the way from the top as the Superview's bottom, which makes the red button 60% up from the bottom of the screen.

Whew!  And that's it!

---

[image: iPhone6s Plus]

---

[image: iPhone 6s]

---

[image: iPhone 5s]

---

[image: iPhone 4s]

Comment: And where do i have to write those lines?

Comment: Ah ok, it's just that i don't really understand what constraint symbol i have to click among the ones at the bottom of the screen..i'm sorry, i don't want to bother you, but it looks like you have right what i need, so i have to understand it

Comment: My god thank you very much. It works perfectly, i'm so happy right now :D
Actually i didn't need the 8th, because the branch is going to move downwards, but i didn't tell you, so sorry. 
Thank you really much again, you're my savior.

And one last thing..again, i don't want to bother you, but since it's clear that you're really good at this and that i am not, could we keep in touch in some way? Email, facebook or whatever you want  (if you want). I promise i won't ask too many questions.. actually a have no questions right now, i was only having troubles with the constrains, but in case..

Comment: The best thing is to continue asking questions on Stack Overflow. You can reply to this comment to notify me that you've posted a question and I'll take a look if I can.

Comment: Ehi, i'm having a problem. I tried to do exactly the same for a red button on the left side, but it doesn't work

Comment: Ehi, is it possible that the text inside a label affects the behavior of ImageViews and Button? Because I'm having this problem. In my code there's no relationship between this label and the other objects, and yet it happens. I would tell you more but here i can't and I'm not allowed to ask any question for some days

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38101089/bug-in-xcode-when-the-text-is-put-into-a-label

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38238667/how-to-decrease-constantly-time-interval-in-an-imageview-animation

Answer (score 1):

1. First give a height to your branch button.
2. Then give leading space to trunc button zero and trailing space to superview zero.

Now only one more information is required for xcode to function autolayout properly.i.e.the y postion of branch button.
if you want your branch position to be vertically centre

3. Give vertically centre in container constaint to branch button