# How to decrease constantly time interval in an ImageView animation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I need to reduce constantly the time interval in an ImageView animation. 
I have a button to start it and then let's say I want to decrease the time interval pushing another button, how can I do it? When I press the first button I have to set the time interval and then it is constant, but I need to change it.

Can you help me?

Comment: As is so often requested, please show your code for what you've tried, and describe where it fell short. It strikes me that you ought to be able to calculate how far the animation has gone, or track it, and using that you could then stop the animation and immediately resume it with the changed interval

Comment: Well the situation is the one I've described. Anyway how can I track the animation? It's just that it starts when a button is pressed, so once pressed I can modify it anymore. But it seems a good idea the one to track it, can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Post the code so there's a starting point?